# Issue with date field comparison in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame ('df') and I am trying to filter the `date` column to only include data before 2020. I have tried two approaches to identify the correct date axis and both are always True, regardless of what the date is. Any suggestions?

Approach #1:

```
df['jan2020'] = pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01')
for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    df['boolCol'] = (df.iloc[row,0] <= df['jan2020'])
df.head(500)
```

Approach #2:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
start_date = df['date'].min()
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01')
mask = (df['date'] >= start_date) & (df['date'] <= end_date)
df['mask']=mask
print(df['mask'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['date']) < '2020-01-01']`